# Streams associated with Socket

Tags: java

When using Scanner/ PrintWriter to manipulate those streams, do we need to close them explicitly or does closing the socket, close the Scanner and PrintWriter objects as well?

Comment: I think you should close the `PrintWriter`, not the `Socket`.  There might be data buffered inside the`PrintWriter` that still needs to be written. I don't think the `Scanner` matters, close either it or the `Socket` will have the same effect.  However, I didn't double check the documentation so take that with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the java IO classes use '[Decorator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern)' pattern to wrap the raw types. Closing a socket object directly will not close the Scanner/PrintWriter, but closing Scanner/Printwrite will cascade the operation to under laying raw type.

If you close Socket directly, then the code which depends on 'Scanner/Printwriter' may get unexpected results.

Most of the Decorated classes, provide wrapped type methods and cascade the operation, but it is always better to check the source of Decorated class.

In case of 'PrintWriter', it invokes 'close' on writer object.

```
public void close() {
    try {
        synchronized (lock) {
            if (out == null)
                return;
            out.close();
            out = null;
        }
    }
    catch (IOException x) {
        trouble = true;
    }
}
```

And flush() will not close the stream, but makes sure that everything in buffer is written to the target.

Comment: So, are you saying that we need to close all three explicitly?

Comment: Like K139 mentioned, you just need to close the Scanner/PrintWriter. When you invoke the close() method on these objects, the underlying/wrapped stream will be flushed (if needed) and closed. Just take a look at the source code ;)

Comment: What if I explicitly flush? Then what?